# Отправка логина и пароля с клиента на сервер

Tags: php, java, oracle, клиент-сервер

Не получается написать скрипт, который будет принимать данные отправленные с клиента (android) и затем сверять их с базой данных Oracle, затем отправлять ответ клиенту, что пара найдена и в клиенте будет выполнятся вход

Вот, что у меня получилось на данные момент

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$response = array();

$connect = oci_connect("", "","");
if($connect == false)
{
  $response['status'] = 'NOT_CONNECT';
}
else
{   
  $parseLogPass = oci_parse($connect, 'SELECT ID_CUSTOMER, PASSWORD FROM CUSTOMERS');
  $ID_CUSTOMER = $_POST['ID_CUSTOMER'];
  $PASSWORD = $_POST['PASSWORD'];
  $ex = oci_execute($parseLogPass);

  if(!$ex)
  {
    $response["status"] = "FAILED";
  } else {
    $response["status"] = "SUCCESS";
  }
  oci_free_statement($parseLogPass);
  oci_close($connect);
  $connect = null;
}
echo json_encode($response);
die();
?>
```

Скрипт вставки данных работает нормально, но сабж не знаю как доделать

Comment: А в чем заключается не правильная работа скрипта? Опишите если не сложно, нам трудно воспроизвести ошибку без вашей базы данных.

Comment: Он не доделан, я прост не знаю как дальше делать.

Comment: Просто вставка записей работает

Comment: Сама структура отправки, на сервер   $ID_CUSTOMER = $_POST['ID_CUSTOMER'];
  $PASSWORD = $_POST['PASSWORD'];, как то по другому должно бытб